# Difference and nuances of std::uint8_t(-1) vs std::uint8_t(0xffu)

Tags: c++

I have seen the use *std::uint8_t(-1)* for example here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

The CPP reference is illustrating endianness swap and I'm wondering what is the difference compared to a *std::uint8_t(0xffu)*?

On x86 there doesn't seem any difference:
https://godbolt.org/z/Kb7v8K1nT

My question could be reading into it too much and it's just a convention how somebody writes code and there is no deeper meaning to it. However, I suspect it's due to the portability of the code on some esoteric architectures where *CHAR_BIT != 8*

But then I was wondering in a case of byte order swap which needs to be 8-bit aligned then I would expect the *std::uint8_t(0xffu)* and forcing to do 8-bit calculations even when the *CHAR_BIT != 8* then that would produce more portable code as it would be expected not to change between platforms? For example, when I'm producing TCP/IP packets and need to have specific endianness (and possibly swap some values), they need to be the values be same no matter what underlying architecture is used.

Maybe in a nibble, char swap (where we expect the size of the type to change and mechanism to adjust) then the *std::uint8_t(-1)* would be better?

In essence with *std::uint8_t(-1)* we are saying set all bits high no matter how many bits are there (even more if CHAR_BIT > 8), while with *std::uint8_t(0xffu)* we want 8-bit set (we get less if CHAR_BIT < 8)?

Or is there something I'm completely missing?

Comment: It rather depends on which C++ standard you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks @Nicol Bolas, I prefer to use C++17 and sometimes C++20. Is there some nuance difference I'm missing?

Comment: *while with std::uint8_t(0xffu) we want 8-bit set (we get less if CHAR_BIT < 8)?* `uint8_t` wont exist then, unless the implementation provides an 8 bit type as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the clarification, I was not 100% sure especially considering some very esoteric architectures.

Comment: An alternative is `std::uint8_t(~0u)`, which avoids the 1's complement *vs* 2's complement representation of -1.  C++ now requires the C++ abstract machine to behave as if 2's complement, so it may be less important than in the past (assuming you target a 1's complement machine).

Comment: `CHAR_BIT < 8` is not allowed in C or C++ implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shortcut to get the maximum value of an unsigned type without having to care how wide it is.  All unsigned types behave in modulo 2<sup>n</sup> so `unsigned_type(-1)` is the same as `std::numeric_limits<unsigned_type>::max()`.

Comment: So I was thinking of changing the bit width of the uint8_t, while it's more about an easy change between the types like uint16_t vs uint8_t without having to resolve to rewrite the literal number?

Comment: Yes, it helps with refactoring like that.  You wont have to update the *magic number*.  While you can consider `-1` a magic nuimber, the expression `unsgined_type(-1)` is a well defined constant, well at least as defined as it can be depending on what exactly `unsigned_type` is. For instance, `unsigned long{-1}` will always give you the max value (all bits set), while  `unsigned long{0xffffffffu}` may or may not be correct depending on the implemtation off `unsigned long` (windows 4 bytes, *Nix 8 bytes)

Comment: Right, now I see an advantage with templates, where we might not even know the type

Comment: @MooingDuck C++ has always mandated that *Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the
value representation of that particular size of integer*  That means `-1` always becomes the max value.

Comment: On a tangent of 'unsigned long{0xffffffffu}' would using bigger number and 'lu' or 'llu' be safer compared to 'u' and let the literal be cast/truncated away for the worst-case scenario. But now I see the -1 as the safest anyway

Comment: @AntonKrug Personally I would use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned_type>::max()` and not worry about it.  I like my code to be expressive and `unsigned_type(-1)` works, I find `std::numeric_limits<unsigned_type>::max()` is much more self documenting.

Comment: I see, so instead of depending on some quirk of overflowing and knowing that it's an unsigned number and it will go to max, just stating out loud what the intend is instead of letting the reader figure it out. Thank you very much for the answer and discussion.